# Trying to uninstall Bitwig from my computer with the .deb package missing

Tags: software-uninstall

I am trying to uninstall Bitwig from my computer and I'm not sure as to how. I currently do not have the .deb package and a `sudo apt-get remove bitwig` does not seem to be working. Bitwig is not on the Software Center either.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What is the error when running `sudo apt-get remove bitwig`

Comment: @Maythux E: `Unable to locate package bitwig`

Comment: This means you can't uninstall the package bitwig because you haven't installed it yet

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: I got a .deb package and opened it with Software Centre. I proceeded to install it after this. Maybe downloading Synaptic could help me?

Comment: It is required to know which package is installed from deb. Can you post output of `dpkg-deb -I /path/to/.deb | grep Package:`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you type it in as

```
sudo apt-get remove bitwig-studio
```

It will uninstall after that. You're only giving it part of the name to look for. That's why it can't find it.

Answer (score 1):

Either:

A.) attempt to install Bitwig again from the repos or a .deb

B.) run `sudo dpkg --force --remove --purge bitwig`

Answer (score 1):

Simply search in the list of the installed packages:

```
dpkg -l | grep -P '^ii\s+bitwig'
```

And remove the packages with

```
sudo apt-get remove <correct_package_name>
```

No need to download the deb again.

Answer (score 0):

So after downloading the `.deb` package, I had to open in it software center and then uninstall the program. I am certainly looking for more efficient ways of uninstalling a program if I have already lost the `.deb` package.

Answer (score -1):

With respect to your command:

> @Maythux E: Unable to locate package bitwig

This means that the package called `bitwig` is not installed in your system, and so you can't uninstall a package which is already not installed!!